# How to access public enum of a class from another file : C++

Tags: c++, enums

This is my `SimplePizzaFactory.h`

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SIMPLE_PIZZA_FACTORY_H
#define SIMPLE_PIZZA_FACTORY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Pizza.h"
#include "cheesePizza.h"
#include "veggiePizza.h"

using namespace std;

class SimplePizzaFactory{
public:
enum PizzaType {
         cheese,
         veggie
         };
Pizza* createPizza(PizzaType type);
    };

#endif
```

My `SimplePizzaFactory.cpp`

```
#include "SimplePizzaFactory.h"

Pizza* SimplePizzaFactory::createPizza(PizzaType type)
{
    switch(type){
        case cheese:
                       return new cheesePizza();

        case veggie:
                       return new veggiePizza();
        }
        throw "Invalid Pizza Type";
    }
```

This is my `PizzaStore.h`

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PIZZA_STORE_H
#define PIZZA_STORE_H
#include "SimplePizzaFactory.h"

class PizzaStore{
SimplePizzaFactory* factory;
public:
PizzaStore(SimplePizzaFactory* factory);
void orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type);
    };

#endif
```

And this is my `PizzaStore.cpp`

```
#include "PizzaStore.h"

using namespace std;

PizzaStore::PizzaStore(SimplePizzaFactory* factory){
    this->factory=factory;
    }


void PizzaStore::orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type){
    Pizza* pizza=factory.createPizza(type);
    Pizza->prepare();
    Pizza->bake();
    Pizza->cut();
    Pizza->box();
    }
```

When I am trying to compile my `PizzaStore.cpp` I am getting below error:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c PizzaStore.cpp -o PizzaStore.o
In file included from PizzaStore.cpp:1:0:
PizzaStore.h:10:37: error: ‘SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype’ has not been declared
 void orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type);
                                     ^
PizzaStore.cpp:12:49: error: variable or field ‘orderPizza’ declared void
 void PizzaStore::orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type){
                                                 ^
PizzaStore.cpp:12:29: error: ‘Pizzatype’ is not a member of ‘SimplePizzaFactory’
 void PizzaStore::orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type){
```

All files are in the same folder, but still it is not able to find `SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type`  though it is defined as `public`.

I tried making it `static` as well as `extern` but no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused by a typo. Use

```
void orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::PizzaType type); // Uppercase 'T' in PizzaType.
```

instead of

```
void orderPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::Pizzatype type);
```